# Why a Teichmüller map is not a pseudo-Anosov?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, foliations, teichmuller-theory

Let $X$ be a Riemannian surface. Suppose $f:X\to X$ is a Teichmüller map with respect to a quadratic differential $q$ on $X$. This means that, if $q=dz^2$ in local coordinates in a neighborhood of nonzero point of $q$, then $f=Kx+\frac1Ky$ for $z=x+iy$ and for a constant $K$ which does not depend on local coordinates.

My question is: Why is $f$ not a pseudo-Anosov map for horizontal and vertical foliations of $q$ (defined as $q(v)>0$ and $q(v)<0$)? It seems that $f$ multiplies ther transversal meashuers by $\frac1K$ and $K$. Maybe whe should suppose $k\ne1$, are there any other reasons for a Teichmüller map not to be a pseudo-Anosov?

The question is motivated by comparing the Teichmüller existence theorem and the Nielsen-Thurston classification. On the one hand, every map $X\to X$ is homotopic to a Teichmüller map. On the over hand, periodic and reducible maps shouldn't be pseudo-Anosov?

Comment: I think you may be confused.  Usually, a Teichmuller map is between distinct (marked) Riemann surfaces, and not from a Riemann surface to itself.  Perhaps you have two different markings on the given surface X?

Comment: @SamNead i think we need to assume the markings for $X$ coincide, and $f$ to be the map not homotopic to identity

Comment: Even if the map is from $X$ to itself, to be pA, it needs to preserve the vertical/horizontal foliations on $X$, while Teichmuller map only preserves  them **after** you choose two sets of conformal coordinates on $X$ (regarded as both domain and the range of the map), effectively replacing $f$ with compositions $\phi \circ f \circ \psi$. This pre/post composition messes up VH foliations completely.

Comment: @MoisheKohan in other words, $f$ may have initial differential $q_1$ and terminal differential $q_2$, which may not coincide, even up to isotopy (do i understand your argument correctly?)

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev - That does not work.  The Teichmuller map is required to be homotopic to the "change of marking" map.  For an overview, see Section 11.1.3 of "A primer on mapping class groups".

Comment: @AndreyRyabichev Right.

Comment: @MoisheKohan okay, so this is an aswer. thank you!

Comment: @SamNead the Teichmuller existence theorem says that in any homotopy class of maps $X\to X$ there is a Teichmuller map. but the initial and terminal differentials for this Teichmuller map can be different up to isotopy, so there will be no pair of foliations with respect to which the map will be pseudo-anosov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $f$ is a Teichmuller map with respect to **a pair** of quadratic differentials $q_1,q_1$ on $X$ --- initial differential and terminal differential. More precisely, $f$ maps the horisontal/vertical foliation of $q_1$ to the horisontal/vertical foliation of $q_2$.

To verify that $f$ is pseudo-anosov we need to constuct one pair of transversal measured foliations which is mapped by $f$ to itself. But $q_1$ and $q_2$ may not coincide up to isotopy, so their pairs of horisontal and vertical foliations will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the definition of Teichmuller space.  You might want to look at "A primer on mapping class groups" by Farb and Margalit (in particular Chapters 10 through 14).

Answer (score -1):

If the initial and terminal quadratic differentials of a Teichmuller map coincide, then it is a pseudo-anosov map.